# Joomla, include content

Tags: joomla, module

I am building one web site. I build some modules which hold menu, logo, news... Inside a news module I have link Read more, and when I click on that link it's open new web page. Problem is I can't see any text in this new windows.

How I can include module which will display text like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give us a lot more information before we can answer. I can tell you this though -

Joomla builds a site based on the default template. The template will have an index.php file that will be the basis for each page. Joomla parses the URL query string to determine what "page" is supposed to display. In that template there should be a bit of code that tells Joomla to display the output of the appropriate template. It looks like this -

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

The output of your "news module" should display here. The template will also have various positions that display around the component, these are called module positions. They will typically look like this -

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml" />
```

This would display the modules that have been placed in the "right" position.

The reason you don't see any text can be anything, your template, the component, an error in a module, bad CSS, bad javascript, the list is infinite. We need to know what component you are using, the modules, the code being executed, and a link to the site would be nice.

Comment: Well, i am building my template which include few positions: news, aboutAs and content. I include those modules like <jdoc:include type="modules" name="aboutAs" />.... I use mod_articleasmodule module to load article in aboutAs module. This article has some text and read more link to read more. When I click read more i get just blank page. I suppose that I need to include some joomla module to my web page to see hole article. Can you please help me?

Comment: Make sure that you have the "component" in your template, it is required and most likely why your article page is blank. I highly recommend reading the documentation - http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_1.5_Template_Tutorial

Comment: Yap, I include <jdoc:include type="component" /> in my template and everything works now fine. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to create a new custom module in joomla. In this custom module you can paste you HTML or insert you content and from Read More button in the bottom of the editor you can insert the read more link in the content.
I think it will be work fine.